# How to simulate genericity using inheritance?

Tags: oop, generics, inheritance

I do not understand how to simulate genericy using inheritance, I am consulting the article "Genericity versus Inheritance" of Bertand Meyer, but I still do not understand it. I would apreciate a clearer explanation.

Answer (score 1):

In some programming languages you can simulate genericy using inheritance with abstract type members.
Here is an example using scala. It should be understandable even if you don´t know scala.

```
class Collection {
type T;
//all methods are using T for the contained type.
}
```

I´m not sure but in c++ type would be typedef.
Following this approach you can get a collection with elements of type A by subtyping the collection and specifying type T to A:

```
class IntCollection extends Collection {
type T = Int; 
//...
}
```

This solutions has some shortcomings in relation to generics or templates but also offers benefits.
If you are interested then consider reading this:http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=270195
Abstract Type Members versus Generic Type Parameters in scala.
again you don´t have to know scala to understand the post.
edit: to cite just one sentence:
At least in principle, we can express every sort of parameterization as a form of object-oriented abstraction.
Hope that helped

Answer (score 1):

Generics are needed only in static typed languages (or those with type-hinting) - because you do not want to lose that hardly acquired type-safety.

If your (static) language does not have them, it's probably time to think about different one - simulating using inheritance is ugly hack.

Or better - think about dynamic languages and test driven development. You'll gain much more power (everything is generic, no need for typing) and tests will represent your contract - including concrete examples - which is what even the best type-safe abstraction simply can't do. (because it's abstract)

Answer (score 0):

In the general case, you can't do it. That's why OO languages have had things like templates and generics added to them. For example, all attempts to create generic containers in C++ prior to the introduction of templates foundered or were almost  completely unusable.

Comment: And what happens if I work with pointers to a base class that summarizes the functionality of its derived classes?

Comment: @two_d Don't know - but that is not genericity in the general sense.